# Mobx: add new (array) property to observable object

Tags: javascript, arrays, observable, mobx

I have an observable object, where I want to store some data.
Keys are unique IDs for my customer entity, and values are arrays of customers' orders (which are objects themselves).

I initialize an object with:

```
@observable data =  {};
```

Then, when I get data from network, I want to store them, using:

```
@action
saveData(customerId, ordersForCustomer) {
  this.data = extendObservable(this.data, {
    [customerId]: observable(ordersForCustomer);
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, it seems my object (or its properties) are not being watched.

Why is this? And how can I fix this? Is there something special I need to know about how observable objects work with arrays as its values?

Comment: It will be mutated so you don't need `this.data = ...`. Try just `extendObservable(this.data, { [customerId]: ordersForCustomer }`. Does that work?

Comment: No, it doesn't. I solved my problem by using observable map. But still, I would like to know what was the case.

Answer (score 8):

This problem is brought up in the [**Common pitfalls & best practices**](https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html) section of the documentation:

> MobX observable objects do not detect or react to property assignments
>   that weren't declared observable before. So MobX observable objects
>   act as records with predefined keys. You can use
>   `extendObservable(target, props)` to introduce new observable
>   properties to an object. However object iterators like `for .. in` or
>   `Object.keys()` won't react to this automatically. If you need a
>   dynamically keyed object, for example to store users by id, create
>   observable _map_s using
>   [**observable.map**](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/map.html).

So instead of using `extendObservable` on an observable object, you could just add a [**new key to a map**](http://jsbin.com/sibuzibamu/edit?js,output):

```
@observer
class App extends Component {
  @observable data = asMap({});
  constructor() {
    super();
    setInterval(() => {
      this.data.set(Math.random().toString(36).slice(-5), Math.random());
    }, 1000);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div> 
        { this.data.entries().map(e => <div> {e[1]} </div>) }
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: As of today, at least, it looks like the text about using maps has moved to [the pitfalls page](https://mobx.js.org/best/pitfalls.html). There's also a decent discussion about maps in a video by Weststrate here: [*Use observable objects, arrays, and maps to store state in MobX*](https://egghead.io/lessons/react-mobx-fundamentals-using-observable-objects-arrays-and-maps-to-store-state), with maps-specific info starting around 2:28. Still wish you could just wrap `{}` like you can `[]` and have hashes shimmed (no new OM) like observable arrays. No dice, apparently.